# Cannot Access about:flags in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, plotly

> about:flags  Provides the Following message : Navigation to the
>   Webpage was Canceled.

Can Somebody help with this? I am using windows 7 , IE 11 and trying to load webGL Components on the browser

Answer (score 0):

About:flags only exists on Microsoft Edge, not on IE.

Comment: Hey , thanks for the reply but nothing of that sorts is mentioned in the link provided here. Please let me know if there is any other document if you referring to. [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn394063(v=vs.85).aspx]

Comment: Your link is broken for me.